# std::map very slow if contents were deleted

Tags: c++, performance, debugging, eclipse-cdt, stdmap

I've discovered a stange behaviour and I don't know, why it is as it is. Look at this code here:

```
        std::map<size_t, std::vector<Resource*>> bla;
        for(int i = 0; i<100000; i++) {
            std::vector<Resource*> blup;
            blup.push_back(new Resource());
            bla[i] = blup;
        }
        for (auto& resources : bla) {
            for (auto resource : resources.second) {
                delete resource;                        // <---- this delete here
            }
            resources.second.clear();
        }
        bla.clear();                                    // <---- this clear here
```

If I run this program in eclipse-debugger, the clear() on the last line took several seconds (too long in my opinion). For bigger maps (>10M elements) it needs up to several minutes(!).

But if I comment out the delete statement in the inner loop, then the clear() function become very fast (as fast as I expect it to be).

Without debugger the code is fast in both cases (with and without delete).

The class "Resource" is a small container class, containinig 2 uint64_t's and a std::string (and ofcourse some methods).

Why is clear() slow? And why it speeds up, if I don't delete the pointers. I don't understand it, because I even clear the vectors in the map. So the map should not see any pointers, it is a map between uint64_t and std::vectors.

I am using MinGw_64 for Windows (msys64, msys2-x86_64-20210419), and Eclipse.

Now I have switched to map-only without vectors. And all is fine with this. Clear is super fast, even, if I delete the pointers. But without vectors I have to think about my algorithm a little bit.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to worry about performance in debug code. Especially when a debugger is attached. And even more so when you judge speed by your opinion and have no precise meassurement (how did you even meassure this?). I suggest to stop worrying until you can prove (with a profiler) that your application has a bottleneck.

Comment: Wild guess: your heap got fragmented to bits and is being reorganized as the deallocations return memory (if you don't give it back, this doesn't happen). You could try this with a different allocator that makes an effort to avoid fragmentation, e.g. [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc).

Comment: _"...If I run this program in eclipse-debugger..."_ test a release build if you are timing things.

Comment: If you don't delete the objects the pointers point to, then they'll leak.  Generally considered bad, although there are some scenarios where that's a useful strategy.

Comment: Is there a reason why Resource has to be allocated on the heap?

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's hard to give a definitive answer. But Eclipse? IMHO vscode in combination with cmake is a much more productive setup.

Comment: @dratenik Your answer is very interesting and I think, it is the right direction. For others: this is not a question about eclipse vs world (btw. eclipse uses GDB) or debug vs release (-g vs -o3). This question asks about a deep non-trivial and interesting problem. And: I just wondered what happens there. :) This is not a productive code AND it is already a minimal reproducible example.